# Building Socket Connections between Servers: Timeout exception

Tags: java, sockets, timeoutexception, socket-timeout-exception

I'm new to Java Socket programming. What I'm trying to do is make socket connections between multiple servers (Simulation of a Distributed System).
When I try to do so with the following Java code, it returns a timeout Exception (other servers are in execution and waiting to accept), Please help me fix it:

```
// a function that sends request to the given IP and port
//myservers is an array of a class that stores IP, PORT, STATUS, Data Input and Data output streams of a connection.
public boolean request(String ip, int port, int index)
{
   try
   {
     InetSocketAddress serverSock=new InetSocketAddress(ip,port);
     Socket otherserver=new Socket();
     otherserver.connect(serverSock);
     if(otherserver.isConnected())
     {
       myservers[index].sock=otherserver;
       myservers[index].setup(); // method that makes Data streams
       myservers[index].status="active";
       return true;
      }
     else
     {
        return false;
      }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Connection Error", 
    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return false;
   }
}

//function that calls the above-mentioned function in a loop is following:
public void makeConnections()
{
  int connected=0;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    String a=request(myservers[i].ip,myservers[i].port,i);
    if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
    {
        connected++;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Stack trace please. NB `isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you are testing it. If the `connect()` failed, an exception would have been thrown. Don't write pointless code. The distinction between `return "failure"` and `return "failed"` eludes me.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm new to Socket programming in JAVA. Kindly provide a solution if you have any.